# How to grep/split a word in middle of %% or $$

Tags: linux, perl, split, grep

I have a variable from which I have to grep the which in middle of %% adn the word which starts with $$. I used split it works... but for only some scenarios.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $lastline ="%Filters_LN_RESS_DIR%\ARC\Options\Pega\CHF_Vega\$$(1212_GV_DATE_LDN)";
my @lastline_temp = split(/%/,$lastline);
print @lastline_temp;
my @var=split("\\$\\$",$lastline_temp[2]);
print @var;
```

I get the o/p as expected. But can i get the same using Grep command. I mean I dont want to use the `array[2]` or `array[1]`. So that I can replace the values easily.

Comment: This is very unclear. Please write what you expect as a correct result if all works optimally fine.

Comment: Can you show example input, and the "split" command you used which sometimes works - and also when your "split" command fails?

Answer (score 1):

First, be very careful in your use of **quotes**, I'm not sure if you don't mean
`'%Filters_LN_RESS_DIR%\ARC\Options\Pega\CHF_Vega\$$(1212_GV_DATE_LDN)'`
instead of
`"%Filters_LN_RESS_DIR%\ARC\Options\Pega\CHF_Vega\$$(1212_GV_DATE_LDN)"`
which might be a different string. For example, if evaluated, `"$$"` means the variable `$PROCESS_ID`.

After trying to solve riddles (not sure about that), and quoting your string

```
my $lastline = 
          '%Filters_LN_RESS_DIR%\ARC\Options\Pega\CHF_Vega\$$(1212_GV_DATE_LDN)'
```

differently, I'd use:

```
my ($w1, $w2) = $lastline =~ m{ %        # the % char at the start
                               ([^%]+)   # CAPTURE everything until next %
                                [^(]+    # scan to the first brace
                                \(       # hit the brace
                               ([^)]+)   # CAPTURE everything up to closing brace
                              }x;
print "$w1\n$w2";
```

to extract your words. Result:

```
Filters_LN_RESS_DIR
1212_GV_DATE_LDN
```

But what do you mean by *replace the values easily*. Which values?

#### Addendum

Now lets extract the "words" delimited by `'\'`. Using a simple split:

```
my @words = split /\\/,  # use substr to start split after the first '\\'
                  substr $lastline, index($lastline,'\\');
```

you'll get the words between the backslashes if you drop the last entry (which is the `$$(..)` string):

```
pop @words;                # remove the last element '$$(..)'
print join "\n", @words;   # print the other elements
```

Result:

```
ARC
Options
Pega
CHF_Vega
```

Does this **work better with grep**? Seems to:

```
 my @words = grep /^[^\$%]+$/, split /\\/, $lastline;
```

and

```
 print join "\n", @words;
```

also results in:

```
 ARC
 Options
 Pega
 CHF_Vega
```

Maybe that is what you are after? What do you want to do with these?

Regards

rbo

Comment: As per my code i'l get the result as lastline_temp = Filters_LN_RESS_DIR and for the var= 1212_GV_DATE_LDN. But i need the words between %% and $$ not starting with (

Comment: Do you need the "words" delimited by `'\'`? Then, see my addendum.

Comment: Yes.. Thanks Addendum. I was able to grep the words. Thanks all For the Help!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how you can get the output you expect. Because you put your data in "busy" quotes (interpolating, double, ...), it comes out being stored as:

```
'%Filters_LN_RESS_DIR%ARCOptionsPegaCHF_Vega$01212_GV_DATE_LDN)'
```

- See [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) and perhaps read [*Interpolation in Perl*](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html)
- Notice that the backslashes are *gone*. A backslash in interpolating quotes simply means "treat the next character as literal", so you get literal `'A'`, literal `'O'`, literal `'P'`, ....
- That `'0'` is the value of `$(` (aka [`$REAL_GROUP_ID`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24REAL_GROUP_ID)) which you *unwittingly* asked it to interpolate. So there is *no* sequence `'$$'` to *split* on.

Can you get the same using a `grep` command? It depends on what "the same" is. You save the results in *arrays*, the purpose of `grep` is to exclude things from the arrays. You will neither have the arrays, nor the *output* of the arrays if you use a non-trivial grep: `grep {; 1 } @data`.

Actually you can get the exact same result with this regular expression, assuming that the single string in `@vars` is the "result".

```
m/%([^%]*)$/
```

Of course, that's no more than

```
substr( $lastline, rindex( $lastline, '%' ) + 1 );
```

which can run 8-10 times faster.